# Reference current context when setting jQuery plugin options

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have the following jQuery plugin (this is just an example to demonstrate the point):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.colourise = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            color: "black"
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).css("color", options.color);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

which I want to apply to the following markup:

```
<div data-color="red">
    This text should be red.    
</div>
<div data-color="blue">
    This text should be blue
</div>
<div data-color="green">
    This text should be green
</div>
```

If the value I want to pass as one of the options of a plugin depends on the element, how do I apply it?  At the moment I can only get this working by doing:

```
$(function () {
    // This feels a bit wrong to have to use a .each() here, but how else do we do it?
    $("div").each(function () {
        $(this).colourise({
            color: $(this).data("color")
        });
    });
});
```

I.e. by iterating over each one with the .each() method and applying the plugin to each element individually (which kinda makes the this.each() inside the plugin a bit redundant).  It feels like I should be able to do something like:

```
$(function () {
    $("div").colourise({
        color: [get context of this "div" somehow].data("color")
    });
});
```

But I can't use $(this) or this here because they refer to the document.

Sorry for the lack of a http://jsfiddle.net/, but the site is really slow for me at the moment, they must be having a few issues.

Comment: No, there is no way... you could only test inside the plugin, in the `each` loop, whether a `data-color` attribute is set and take its value.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, I probably should have added that the actual plugin in question isn't mine, so I can't change the plugin code. I need to pass the value via the options.

Comment: Ah ok.... then I don't think there is any way if the plugin does not allow callbacks, such as @Esailija showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each` is exactly what you need.

When you call the method on a multi-element set without a `.each` callback, you're creating a single options object that gets used within the plugin for every element in the set.

You can't vary it per-element without making a separate object for each element.

Comment: Now I think about it, that makes sense, we're just executing the plugin function once against a collection of matched elements.  Thanks SLaks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a callback to retrieve color like this

```
function getColor(){
return $.data( this, "color" );
}
```

Colourise with the callback as option

```
$(function () {
    $("div").colourise({
    color: getColor
    });
});
```

Check if the color option is a callable function

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.colourise = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        color: "black"
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
    var color = options.color;

    color = typeof color =="function" ? color.call( this ) : color;
        $(this).css("color", color);
    });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Esailija, however I can't change the plugin as it's not mine.  I had a look at it and it doesn't look like they support callbacks. +1 for a useful answer otherwise though :-)